# Replacing bathroom light/exhaust fan

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan

Replacing bathroom light exhaust fan. The old one has a white black red and ground wires. The new one just has green white and black. The fan and light are operated by a single switch. How do I connect these?

Comment: I'm a little concerned because it tends to be the smaller, cheaper units that don't allow for separate control of light and fan. Before installation, make sure that the new fan is acceptable in terms of sound level (sones or decibels) and power (CFM). The easiest thing to return is a never-installed item (though the big box stores will take back just about anything).

Comment: How was the old one connected? Was the old one a single switch or two switches?

Comment: What do you have for wires from the building at the fan location? Did you take "before" pictures of the wiring before disconnecting the old fan?